# How to put x button to clear content in input field using angular 5 and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a 'x' button inside an input field using angular 5 and bootstrap but was not successful.

By clicking on 'x' button the content in that input field should get cleared

I tried using

```
<input type="search" id = "search">
```

In CSS:

```
 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
-webkit-appearance: searchfield-cancel-button;
}
input[type="search"]::-ms-clear {
  color: red;
}
```

However, I have a problem with this implementation as the webkit-apperance has the compatibility issue with IE11 (even firefox dont support it) and the 'x' is not showing.

can any one help me to find if there is any solution with Angular 5/6/7 and Bootstrap 4.

I have a solution to work with Jquery and Javascript
https://codepen.io/frosdqy/pen/grbxGW

but looking for pure typescript(Angular) or bootstrap solution.

If someone can help with angular5 it would be a great help!

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. Are you only using the bootstrap css? Because several of their components rely on jquery anyway hence you're already probably including it in your project? Or if you want an "angular" solution, just jack the style of that example and replace the jquery click handler on the `X` and instead do like `(click)="document.getElementById('search').value=''"` and you're done. Unless you're trying to make a whole reusable component or something? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its all about illusion. you create a div. inside that div create a input and button with x. set the input background transparent and border 0. and you will see it.

Comment: I used the approach.  background transparent worked in IE with input[type="search"]::-ms-clear {
  color: red;
}

Answer (score 1):

I found a question that appears to solve an issue similar to yours:
[Position clear button in bootstrap input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695091/position-clear-button-in-bootstrap-input-field)

Comment: @user3854185 Did my answer help you at all?

Comment: Hi Dylan, To certain extent yes. It helped in fixing the position. However, I am looking for binding the key press event associated with it.